# para mudar de mysql para mysqli tenho que alterar o banco?

Tags: php, mysql

Se tenho banco mysql e nos meus documentos em php atualizar para mysqli o banco continuará o mesmo?

Comment: Não vejo o porquê de mudar algo.

Comment: Não precisa mudar de banco.!

Comment: Basta só mudar as funções de php. Importante: Perceba que a ordem dos parâmetros de mysql_connect é diferente de mysqli_connect. (É o inverso)

Comment: Entendi, o banco permanece o mesmo o que muda é só a linguagem

Comment: Você continua chamando pelo php. O que muda é a hora de conectar com o banco. Quando for chamar a query.

Comment: Apesar de só adicionar "i" à maioria das funções, algumas não existem e outras, como o António Alexandre indicou têm a ordem de parâmetros diferente. Além da mysqli_connect, também a mysqli_real_escape_string trocou os parâmetros.